# Building a dataset with dataloader pytorch getting error cannot import name 'read_data_sets'

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, dataloader

Loading data into dataset using pytorch dataloader.
Getting error cannot import name 'read_data_sets'

Tried searaching for results from similar issues.
If there is confusion about file instead of module and it can't find read_data_sets in your file  How do i change to fix?

```
class MRDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, task, plane, train=True, transform=None, weights=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.task = task
        self.plane = plane
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.train = train
        if self.train:
            self.folder_path = self.root_dir + 'train/{0}/'.format(plane)
            self.records = pd.read_csv(
                self.root_dir + 'train-{0}.csv'.format(task), header=None, names=['id', 'label'])
        else:
            transform = None
            self.folder_path = self.root_dir + 'valid/{0}/'.format(plane)
            self.records = pd.read_csv(
                self.root_dir + 'valid-{0}.csv'.format(task), header=None, names=['id', 'label'])

        self.records['id'] = self.records['id'].map(
            lambda i: '0' * (4 - len(str(i))) + str(i))
        self.paths = [self.folder_path + filename +
                      '.npy' for filename in self.records['id'].tolist()]
        self.labels = self.records['label'].tolist()

        self.transform = transform
        if weights is None:
            pos = np.sum(self.labels)
            neg = len(self.labels) - pos
            self.weights = torch.FloatTensor([1, neg / pos])
        else:
            self.weights = torch.FloatTensor(weights)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        array = np.load(self.paths[index])
        label = self.labels[index]
        if label == 1:
            label = torch.FloatTensor([[0, 1]])
        elif label == 0:
            label = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 0]])

        if self.transform:
            array = self.transform(array)
        else:
            array = np.stack((array,)*3, axis=1)
            array = torch.FloatTensor(array)

        # if label.item() == 1:
        #     weight = np.array([self.weights[1]])
        #     weight = torch.FloatTensor(weight)
        # else:
        #     weight = np.array([self.weights[0]])
        #     weight = torch.FloatTensor(weight)

        return array, label, self.weights
```

There is a model and train class to run this.  Arguments specified in train.
Running the train should load data and run through model

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/maincarey/ML/blob/master/MRI.ipynb

Comment: data is MRNet-v1.0 (~5.7G). from stanford MRI samples   - not on my github  https://stanfordmlgroup.github.io/projects/mrnet/